# How can I make my discord.py bot delete every message send on a specific channel?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm making a discord bot, and one of it's features is gonna be the deleting messages sent on a specific channel.

I searched and found some tutorial videos and the closest I got was this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel) == "channelID" and message.content != "":
        await message.delete_message()
```

The problem is that's from a video of 2y ago, so I imagine it's that how it was supposed to be done on an old discord.py version, since this code doesn't work for me(it doesn't give any error that stops the bot form running, but doesn't do what's expected). Anyone knows how to properly do it on discord.py latest versions?

Comment: `delete_message()` doesn't exist (which should give you an error). Don't look at tutorials, they're all outdated, teach terrible code & you won't learn anything other than copy-pasting exactly what they do. Just read the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these two parts:

`str(message.channel) == "channelID"` to `message.channel.id == channelID` (you can convert the channel id to a string for comparision if necessary)

`await message.delete_message()` to `await message.delete()`

Make sure required intents are enabled and your bot has permission to delete messages.